# React Lazy and delaying the load of the component to fall in Suspense

Tags: reactjs

I want to experiment with `Suspense` and `Lazy`.
For this, I was thinking in defer o delay the load of the component for certain time, however, I could not do it.

What I was doing is using setTimeout() at componenDidMount(), then update the state and return that piece of state. But, this is not working as I expected.

Can anyone help me delaying the load of a component with `Lazy` without using browsers tools to fall in `Suspense` fallback?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood your question right, something like this should work for you:

```
const Component = React.lazy(async () => {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, YOUR_DELAY));
  return import('./Component');
});
```